# Is It Practical To Use Nav?

Tags: html, nav

How practical is it to use the `<nav>` element compared to something like `<div id="nav">`?

I know that nav is a fairly new element, and I don't want to use it unless it's basically accepted in all browsers now.

Would I be better off still using a div element with a class/id?

I know this isn't the typical question to ask, but I didn't find to many results on if this should be used more often now, and the few I did were saying that it shouldn't be used as often yet.

UPDATE: Dmitriy provided me a link in a comment that answered this with a great reference website. Many thanks. http://caniuse.com/#search=nav

It seems that this element still lacks functionality in certain mobile browsers so I think I'll avoid it for now.

Comment: The nav element represents a section of a page that links to other pages or to parts within the page: a section with navigation links.  http://caniuse.com/#search=nav

Comment: @Dmitriy Have you looked at the URL you provided? it has no reference to <nav>.

Comment: @JesseElser CanIUse is great, particularly for CSS support.

Comment: I'll be bookmarking it for sure. :)

Comment: Good call @Dmitriy - I use *caniuse.com* all the time, and was too busy linking to it in my answer to notice your comment about it.

Comment: @JesseElser if you use a div then add the ARIA role="navigation"to support Assistive Technology (screen readers etc).

Comment: Since two answers linked to it, I wanted to note that w3schools is fairly broadly looked down on by many people on SO, because they often had outright wrong information. Since the advent of [w3fools](http://w3fools.com) pointing out how bad they were, w3schools _has_ improved, but [MDN](http://developer.mozilla.org/) is generally better and more reliable. Also see _CSS-Tricks_, _HTML5 Rocks_, and the _Web Platform Docs_, all linked from [w3fools](http://w3fools.com)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends what browsers you need to support but  seems relatively well supported from IE9 and FF4;

http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-preview/the-nav-element.html

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_nav.asp

I can only suggest you try it and test on your target browsers.

If for some reason you do end up using a div make sure you add  role="navigation"

```
<div id="nav" role="navigation">
```

Comment: I didn't know about the dev.w3 site. Thanks for that one. I did know about w3schools website, but I've seen some people say it wasn't reliable at times so I was asking you guys. Thanks for the other site. :)

Answer (score 1):

The HTML5 semantic elements, including `<nav>`, [are pretty well supported](http://caniuse.com/#feat=html5semantic) in all but the oldest browsers.

If you also include [modernizr.js](http://modernizr.com/docs/#html5inie) you get support in other browsers too, without having to actually write any javascript to do it... merely loading modernizr runs some js to create the elements if they are not natively supported in a browser.

You can, and will be better off, if you switch to `<!DOCTYPE html>` now and make use of the html5 semantic elements now, rather than sticking with `<div class="something">`

Comment: I always use the html5 doctype, but I never used modernizer before. I've seen several sites that recommended it though, so I'll be checking it out as well. Thanks. :)